# php require method wont display css styling

Tags: php, html, css, require, sidebar

I created a `index.php` file that's uses `<?php require("sidebar.html"); ?>` to include a sidebar;  the HTML element of the sidebar shows, however the css styling isn't showing. I've search Google and tried different method but it's not showing, any help would be highly appreciated.

The `sidebar.html` is located in `HTML/` folder. And `index.php` is located in `root/` folder

The css styling for the sidebar is being reference within the `sidebar.html` file

My `css` file is located in `CSS/` folder

new to web development; Trying to make a sidebar that I can call on every page instead of hard-coding it to every page.

Comment: check if all your files are located in the same folder and check your paths.

Comment: Show up some sample codes that your using in `sidebar.html` especially for including your stylesheet

Comment: can you please put some code in your question?

Comment: Seems like you are unable to handle the paths correctly. Can you post your code snippets?

Comment: check and make sure all required files are in path.

Comment: @LittlePhild  in my sidebar.HTML I have my link to my CSS   href="CSS/sidebar.CSS". Than I have the side bar content <div class="sidebar>contents</div> in the CSS file I have the background color set to black and text whit. The HTML show up when I use the require, but not the css                                                        P.S I Dont known how to enter sample codes, do I just paste it in the question box next time?

Comment: @Neha I have my sidebar.CSS in a CSS folder and the sidebar.HTML in a HTML folder and the index.php in the root

Comment: @MelvinArkue, Use this reference in order to learn how to post codes in your question [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thanks guys,  I was able to solve the problem; I wasn't referencing the css file correctly. My sidebar was in a HTML folder and css was in a CSS folder. I didn't use ".../" to go up one level.  This is my first time use stack Overflow and i must say I got the answers I needed very quickly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you include an HTML file into a PHP script, path to all the related files (i.e. files that are referenced in the HTML document) must be relative to the PHP script in which you have included the HTML.

Have a look at the file structure below:

- Home

  - index.php
- Includes

  - Assets

    - style.css
    - action.js
  - header.html

The Assets directory contains CSS and JS files which are included in `header.html`. Now, if `header.html` has to be included in `index.php` that is inside the `Home` directory, the `src/href` attributes need to point to the path of css/js files relative to `index.php`.

Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Includes/Assets/style.css" />
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a BASE URL at the top of the page like below (based on your project directory location).
   Try
    `$baseURL  = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`

   or
    `$baseURL  = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/your_project_dir/";`
2. Use HTML base tag in your `<head>` tag before your`<link>` tags like

   `<html>`
    `<head>`
    `<title>Project Title</title>`
    `<base href="<?php echo $baseURL;">`
    `<link href="your_css_file.css" type="text/css">`
    `</head>`
    `<body>`
     `page content`
     `</body>`
     `</html>`
3. Cross check your "your_css_file.css" location (like css/your_css_file.css or styles/your_css_file.css ...)

Answer (score -2):

Try to add

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

In the first and end of your css require file, the css will read as internal stylesheet. And change the *extension* .css to 
.php